# How to replace JQuery functions such as .each() and .find() with a higher performance equivalent?

Tags: jquery, css, performance

How could I improve the performance of my below JQuery code:

```
var firstRowCellsWidth = new Array();

function initialize();

    $('table.rgMasterTable > tbody > tr:first > td').each(function () {

            firstRowCellsWidth.push({
                normalCellWidth: $(this).width(),
                firstTemplateCellWidth: $(this).find('table > tbody > tr > td:first').width()
            });
        });
}
```

I'm using `:first`, `$(this)`, `.find(, >`, and `each()`. these apparently degrade the performance?

What should they be replaced with? or what are their equivalent native javascript code?

I'd guess using for loop instead of the `each()` method. what about the rest?

Purpose of the code:
To figure out the width of each column of the table. the master table has also a nested table as can be seen.

Thanks,

Comment: What are you trying to do? Rather than asking people to improve code you think is poor ask them to give you a solution to your problem (although you should include what you've already tried)

Comment: @Patrick. I think his question is pretty clear. He's asking about some very specific jQuery features, and how they could potentially be replaced with more efficient code.

Comment: @William : I didn't read the code, though I'm sure you'll agree the English description is much easier to grasp than the code.

Comment: @maxedision: I'd disagree; he is asking how to find out the width of each column of a table in an efficient manner with an inefficient example given in jQuery.

Comment: @William (1) Are nested tables really neccessary? (2) How many `.rgMasterTable` tables are there? Only one? Multiple?

Comment: @Sime; yes the nested tables are necessary and there are 6 layers in the worst case. 2) masterTable is the root so only 1 table exists in that layer but my question was about the performance of the JQuery functions mentioned.

Comment: @William nested tables are never neccessary. If you want performance increase fix your DOM first.

Comment: @William, see my answer for the comparison of JS vs JQuery, regarding speed. I have created some test cases, from which I deduced that the JQuery approach is 2000x slower than the JavaScript approach. Have you already tried the code proposal in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
var firstRowCellsWidth = [];
function initialize(){
  var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
  for(var i=0; i<tables.length; i++){
    if(/(^|\s)rgMasterTable(\s|$)/.test(tables[i].className)){
      //a className is only valid if the className is contained within a space/nothing(^) and a space/nothing($)

      var tcell = tables[i].rows[0].cells; //Any cell
      for(var j=0; j<tcell.length; j++){
        firstRowCellsWidth.push({
          normalCellWidth:tcell[j].offsetWidth,
          firstTemplateCellWidth:tcell[j].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].offsetWidth
         //the first cell of any row of any table = the first occurence of a TD element
        });
      }
      //break;
      //Uncomment the previous line if you want to enumerate through all tables whose class equals .rgMasterTable
    }
  }
}
```

*As efficient as possible, without use of JQuery (frameworks are used too often by lazy scripters who do not mind a loss in computing efficiency).*

Note that an error will be thrown when the document structure does not match your description (`tcell[j].getElementsByTagName("td"[0] is undefined`).

### EDIT: JavaScript vs JQUery in terms of speed

As a response to maxedison (third comment), who questioned my statement that JQuery is less efficient than JavaScript. Copy the code snippets belows and paste them in the location bar (of this page). A prompt will appear, where the number of tests can be specified. After the test has run, an alert pops up, showing the needed amount of milliseconds to perform these tests. Two test cases are provided:

*Native **JavaScript** test case:*

```
javascript:alert((function(m){
for(var i=0, t=new Date; i<m; i++){
  document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[0].cells[0];
}
return (new Date).getTime()-t.getTime();
})(prompt("Native\x20JS,\x20repeat\x20n\x20times:","10000")));
```

***JQuery** test case. Warning: Do not start with a large number of tests:*

```
javascript:alert((function(m){
for(var i=0, t=new Date; i<m; i++){
  $("table > tbody > tr > td:first");
}
return (new Date).getTime()-t.getTime();
})(prompt("JQuery,\20repeat\x20n\x20times","10")));
```

At my 1 year old laptop, using FireFox 3.6.22, **10000** calls using native JavaScript equals **5** JQuery executions.

Comment: you suggest rewriting everything in plain DOM JavaScript?!

Comment: I have updated my answer to make it more clear: Replace your `initialize` function by my proposal. You're missing a curly bracelet (`{`) after `function initialize()`, by the way.

Comment: "frameworks are used too often by lazy scripters who do not mind a loss in computing efficiency" -- JS engines in browsers are so fast these days that "efficiency" is rarely an issue. Efficiency only matters if it causes problems in the real world. Until it does, ease of coding & code maintenance are the priorities. In the OP's case, we've obviously arrived at a point when efficiency needs to be dealt with. But I've written tons of jQuery code and never had reason to worry about efficiency. Anyway, I'll be interested to hear what improvements the OP experiences with your code.

Comment: @maxedison
See my updated answer. My explanation of JS vs JQuery was more suitable at the answer (see **EDIT**).

Comment: I never "questioned your statement that jQuery is less efficient than JavaScript." Of course it is. I was simply saying that more often than not, the "loss in computing efficiency" is negligible, and therefore ease of coding & code maintenance are the priorities. I like the edit though :)

Comment: @maxedison
Code maintenance won't be harder when you don't use Frameworks. Try to read my code proposal, and compare it to the JQuery version. Unless I'm wrong, the code is still perfectly legible. The computing efficiency is still not negligible: A simple `$("body")` is already twice as slow as `document.getElementsByTagName` (absolutely: negligible). More complex calculations are not only relatively incredible inefficient, but also absolutely: The OP's JQuery loop needs at least one second to run 60 times. Especially in a loop, complex JQuery selectors are not recommended.

Comment: I agree that clearly the OP's case is one in which efficiency has become a problem; I stated as much in my first comment. I certainly disagree about code maintenance though. Of course your code is legible, but I think it's hard to make the case that the OP's code isn't easier to read. It's also half as long (not including lines with just closing braces, comments, etc). I basically think using jQuery is great until you reach a point where efficiency becomes a problem. Unless you're developing very complicated, dynamic web apps, efficiency rarely becomes an issue (mobile browsers excluded)

Comment: @maxedison
The compact version of the JQuery framework has a size of 30kB. So, code size is not a strong argument. I agree that JQuery is sufficient for simple applications, especially for inexperienced programmers (cross-browser support). Laziness/ease, however, should never be a reason to sacrifice performance. This comment chain is going into the direction of a discussion. Don't add any more comments which has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: "Don't add any more comments which has nothing to do with the question." Please don't preach that which you don't practice. I have barely argued with anything you said. You have put words into my mouth and ignored the context in which I made my points. "Ease" is absolutely a reason to sacrifice efficiency, so long as the efficiency that is sacrificed is not noticeable to a real human being in a real world. Disagreeing with that is pure ideology. And your point about minified jQuery is completely irrelevant. That has nothing to do with code maintenance. Don't add any more comments.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually experiencing performance problems? It doesn't look like this is the kind of loop that is getting run so many times that saving a couple ms per iteration would make any noticeable difference.

Anyway, I realize you may be asking out of curiosity, so here is one way that performance could be improved:

- before pushing the values, store `$(this)` in a variable. Remember that `$` is actually a function, so `$(this)` means that you are calling the function `$` and passing the argument this to it. As a general rule of thumb, if your'e going to need to use `$(this)` more than once, storing it in a variable will be faster since it avoids making additional `$` function calls.

I'd also be curious to know whether a standard `for` loop would ever be significantly faster than `.each()`. However, when you ask "what are their equivalent native javascript code?", be aware that the entire reason you're using jQuery is because it's a lot easier to write & read, and that most "native javascript" equivalents are going to look & be far more complicated. So that question itself kind of defeats the purpose of using jQuery in the first place, unless of course you really are experiencing some performance issues.

Comment: thanks for the tip on $(this). the problem I'm currently having is that I'm looping through 4-6 hierarchical nested tables using JQuery and the above functions are used in many places but IE freezes for a long time when there are over 100 rows in a table so I thought maybe these codes are degrading its performance.

Comment: Did you try Rob W's solution? Curious to know how much that improves things.

Answer (score 0):

One improvement would be to store a reference to any jQuery object you intent to use more than once..

So instead of using multiple times `$(this)` use

```
var $this = $(this);
```

and use `$this` from now on to refer to that object..

```
function initialize(){
    $('table.rgMasterTable > tbody > tr:first > td').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            firstRowCellsWidth.push({
                normalCellWidth: $this.width(),
                firstTemplateCellWidth: $this.find('table > tbody > tr > td:first').width()
            });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the .each with a native loop likely won't do anything, the .each is just doing a for loop anyway.

Are you actually having problems with speed?

Assuming that you're going to have static layouts for your tables you could figure out how to navigate down using `.childNodes[]`. You would do something like

```
document.getElementById('myTable').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0]
```

. As you can imagine, that gets pretty ugly pretty fast.

You could probably speed up your selectors a little bit by getting rid of the `> trbody >` part, unless you have a table in your `trbody` and another in a `trhead` it's not doing anything.

Comment: > is important; it gets the first direct element and that's what is needed. this suggests that for loop has a higher performance than .each() but haven't verified it myself: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/javascript-for-loop-vs-jquery-each.html

Comment: ...but since you're filtering to the table in the :first tr inside of the main table *anyway*, does it still matter? You haven't posted any of your HTML so it's hard for me to say for sure but I'm just guessing it probably doesn't.

Comment: as far as .each being faster than for, the blog you posted concludes by saying it DOESN'T matter. He sees a difference of 3ms when running 10,000 iterations. How many iterations are you going to be doing?

Comment: like I said > is necessary since e.g. there are other tbody elements in the html but only the first closest to the root should be selected.

Comment: ok but you **don't** need > just to find a child, if you say `$(this).find('tr:first')` it will give you the first `tr` inside of `this` - not the first `tr` on the page.

Comment: these 2 are not the same for your information; 'tr:first' returns the first <tr> after the $(this) element no matter in which level of hierarchy the tr exists whereas '>' returns the first tr after the current element AND where the <tr> is closest level below the root. Assume this: <div id="1"><p><div id="2"></div></p><div id="3"></div></div>. In this example $('#1 > div'); returns div id = 3 whereas $('#1').find('div:first'); returns  the div id = 2.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Since you haven't given any information about your markup, I'm making some assumptions. One assumption that I feel pretty confident in making is that you aren't wrapping your sibling <tr>s in anything that would cause `$(this).find('tr:first');` to return something different than `$(this).find('table > tbody > tr:first');`. Maybe that assumption is incorrect. How could I possibly know that, though, without a representative sample of your markup?